# defficult time to assign the servos in coding

Tags: c++, c, arduino

So I more or lees just got the arudino in a few days ago for a specefic project with four servos clicking down eight buttons on my 3ds. Completely new to coding, I need help with assigning my servos and a photocell in the coding I have been given. Every time I try to give the pin numbers of where the servos are, I get an error somewhere else. I've tried to get this working for days now so any suggestion would be lovely!

```
#include <Servo.h>

// Define the slots (says digital ~PWM) on the Arduino where various parts of the machine will go
/* Diyode CodeShield Constants */
#define SERVO1 2 ); Servo attach ;2
#define SERVO2 3 ); Servo attach ;-3
#define SERVO3 4 ); Servo attach ;4
#define SERVO4 5 ); Servo attach ; -5
#define PIEZO 6 ); attach ; -6
#define BUTTON 9 ); attach 9

// Define a couple constants of length of time in milliseconds
#define CHECK_SCREEN_DELAY 150
#define WALKING_BUTTONPRESS_DURATION 3300

// Define a couple cases, don't mess with these
#define STARTING 1
#define WALKING 2
#define WATCHING 3
#define FOUND 4

//servo1 presses left and up
Servo servo1;
//servo2 presses right and down
;Servo servo2;
//servo3 presses b and y
Servo servo3;
//servo4 presses a and x
Servo servo4;

// Defines the starting positions of the servos. 
// These will need to be adjusted during setup.
int servo1Flat = 108;
int servo1Deflect = 18;
int servo2Flat = 95;
int servo2Deflect = 20;
int servo3Flat = 83;
int servo3Deflect = 15;
int servo4Flat = 65;
int servo4Deflect = 15;
String name = "A";

//Define the photoreceptor.
int photocellPin = 1;     // the cell and 10K pulldown are connected to a1
int photocellReading;     // the analog reading from the sensor divider

//Define counts so the program knows when to collect, hatch, or deposit eggs.
unsigned int mode = 1;
unsigned int egg_count = 0;
unsigned int clutch_count = 0;
unsigned int box_count = 0;
unsigned int bike_count = 0;

//This is the level of light that the program uses to make decisions on whether to collect
//an egg or to hatch one.
unsigned char dark_threshold = 400;

//Setting up and writing in th servos. Don't mess with these.
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.print("Start Unit ");
  Serial.println(name);

  servo1.attach(SERVO1);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);

  servo2.attach(SERVO2);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);

  servo3.attach(SERVO3);
  servo3.write(servo3Flat);

  servo4.attach(SERVO4);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
}
void loop() {

  switch (mode) {
    case STARTING:
      watchButton();
      break;
    case WALKING:
      doWalking();
      break;
    case WATCHING:
      break;
    case FOUND:
      watchButton();
      break;
  }
}
void watchButton() {
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON) == HIGH) {
   mode = WALKING;
  }  
}    

int is_between(long val, long lower, long upper)
{
    return (val > lower && val < upper);
}

//Define the actions to take when you've hatched all your eggs, 
//i.e. go to the PC, deposit the eggs, come back outside and ask for
//another egg.
void tapScreen() {
// Go east and get off bike
  if(clutch_count < 6)
  {
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(4000);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(100);
  servo3.write(servo3Flat - 5*servo3Deflect);
  delay(500);
  servo3.write(servo3Flat);
  delay(600);
//Walk into daycare center and over to pc
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat - 2*servo1Deflect);
  delay(3500);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat - 2*servo1Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
//Open PC, navigate to eggs  
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(2200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat - 4*servo2Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(2300);
//Deposit 5 eggs  
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
//Exit out of PC and walk back outside, get on bike, ask for egg
  servo4.write(servo4Flat + 4*servo4Deflect);
  delay(400);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(2500);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(250);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat - 4*servo2Deflect);
  delay(3000);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(1200);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat - 4*servo2Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(300);
  servo3.write(servo3Flat - 5*servo3Deflect);
  delay(500);
  servo3.write(servo3Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(500);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(400);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(400);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(400);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(400);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(400);
  clutch_count++;
  }
//When the box is full, the program follows these commands, which are
//identical to the above except it changes the box and resets the clutch count.  
  else
  {
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(4000);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(100);
  servo3.write(servo3Flat - 5*servo3Deflect);
  delay(500);
  servo3.write(servo3Flat);
  delay(600);
//Walk into daycare center and over to pc
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat - 2*servo1Deflect);
  delay(3500);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat - 2*servo1Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
//Open PC, navigate to eggs  
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(2200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat - 4*servo2Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(2300);
//Change box, deposit 5 eggs  
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(900);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);  
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(700);
//Exit out of PC and walk back outside, get on bike, ask for egg  
  servo4.write(servo4Flat + 4*servo4Deflect);
  delay(250);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(2500);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
  delay(250);
  servo1.write(servo1Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat - 4*servo2Deflect);
  delay(3000);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(1200);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat - 4*servo2Deflect);
  delay(300);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(300);
  servo3.write(servo3Flat - 5*servo3Deflect);
  delay(500);
  servo3.write(servo3Flat);
  delay(600);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
  delay(500);
  servo2.write(servo2Flat);
  delay(400);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(400);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(400);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(400);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
  delay(200);
  servo4.write(servo4Flat);
  delay(400);
  clutch_count = 1;
  box_count++;
  Serial.print("***BOXES FILLED***: ");
  Serial.println(box_count);
  }
  Serial.print("Clutches: ");
  Serial.println(clutch_count);
  bike_count = 0;
}

//Define the beep that will occur if the program messes up, which
//happens when the program rides back and forth on the bike 50 times without
//the screen darkening. The screen should always darken before riding back and
//forth 50 times due to an egg being accepted from the breeder or hatched.
void beep() {
 analogWrite( PIEZO, 35);
 delay(400);
 digitalWrite(PIEZO, LOW);
}    

void doWalking()
{
    while(1)
    {
        photocellReading = analogRead(photocellPin);
        //As I mentioned above the beep definition, when the program messes up, 
        //i.e. your character ends up in a place they shouldn't be and cannot 
        //collecting eggs, the program follows these commands. It will press "b" a bunch
        //of times, then walk around a bit in case you are in the breeder's house,
        //and then will use Talonflame to fly to in front of the Pokemon center. Then
        //you will deposit any eggs/pokemon you might have (besides Talonflame), you will
        // switch to a new box, and start over.
        if(bike_count >= 50)
        {
          beep();
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo2.write(servo2Flat - 4*servo2Deflect);
          delay(4000);
          servo2.write(servo2Flat);
          delay(200);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat + 4*servo4Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(2500);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat);
          delay(600);
          servo2.write(servo2Flat - 4*servo2Deflect);
          delay(4000);
          servo2.write(servo2Flat);
          delay(200);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat + 4*servo4Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(2500);                                            
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(2000);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat + 4*servo4Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(5000);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat + 4*servo4Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(2000);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(2000);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(1000);
          servo2.write(servo2Flat - 4*servo2Deflect);
          delay(300);
          servo2.write(servo2Flat);
          delay(1000); 
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(1000);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(1500);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(250);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(13000);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat - 5*servo3Deflect);
          delay(500);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(600);
          clutch_count = 6;
          beep();
          tapScreen();
          beep();
          egg_count = 0;
          bike_count = 0;

        }

        //If the screen is bright after asking for an egg and you have fewer than 5 eggs,
        //the program bikes back and forth and asks for an egg.
        else if(photocellReading > 350 && egg_count <5)
        {
          servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
          delay(WALKING_BUTTONPRESS_DURATION);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat);
          delay(50);
          servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
          delay(3200);
          servo2.write(servo2Flat);
          delay(50);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
          delay(WALKING_BUTTONPRESS_DURATION);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat);
          delay(50);
          servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
          delay(3500);
          servo2.write(servo2Flat);
          delay(100);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(200);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(400);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(200);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(400);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(200);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(400);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(200);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(400);
          bike_count++;
            }
        //Deposits eggs if you've hatched them all.
        else if(egg_count >= 10)
          {                
            tapScreen();
            egg_count = 0;
          }

        //Focuses on hatching eggs after you've collected 5 eggs.
        else if(photocellReading > 350 && egg_count >=5)
          {          
          servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
          delay(3300);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat);
          delay(50);
          servo2.write(servo2Flat + servo2Deflect);
          delay(3300);
          servo2.write(servo2Flat);
          delay(50);
          bike_count++;
          }

        //Hatches an egg when the screen goes dark after you've collected 5 eggs.
        else if(photocellReading < 350 && egg_count >=5)
          {
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(19000);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat + servo3Deflect);
          delay(400);
          servo3.write(servo3Flat);
          delay(3000);
          egg_count++;
          Serial.print("Eggs hatched: ");
          Serial.println(egg_count - 5);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat + servo1Deflect);
          delay(800);
          servo1.write(servo1Flat);
          bike_count = 0;
          }

        //If you've collected fewer than five eggs and the screen is still dark after asking
        //for an egg, the program will take the egg.
        else if(photocellReading < 350 && egg_count < 5)
        {
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(200);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(400);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(200);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(400);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(200);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(3000);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(200);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(400);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat - servo4Deflect);
          delay(200);
          servo4.write(servo4Flat);
          delay(400);
          egg_count++;
          Serial.print("Eggs: ");
          Serial.println(egg_count);
          bike_count = 0;
        }

        int curr = analogRead(photocellPin);            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you try to achieve here:

```
#define SERVO1 2 ); Servo attach ;2
#define SERVO2 3 ); Servo attach ;-3
#define SERVO3 4 ); Servo attach ;4
#define SERVO4 5 ); Servo attach ; -5
#define PIEZO 6 ); attach ; -6
#define BUTTON 9 ); attach 9
```

but what you get is, in every place where `SERVO1` appears in the code, it is substituted with `2 ); Servo attach ;2` string. So `servo1.attach(SERVO1);` becomes `servo1.attach(2 ); Servo attach ;2);` which is nonsense. Just make the defines like `#define SERVO1 2` and you should be fine.